# ABAddressBook detect contact record changes

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

Is there a way to detect which contact records have changed ?

I understand there are 2 options to detect change:

1. `kABDatabaseChangedNotification` and
   `kABDatabaseChangedExternallyNotification`
2. `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback`

I would like to detect each contact that has been changed. How would I be able to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no way to detect the individual changes.

Couple of points to keep in mind:

- You need to use `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback1 to
  specify the callback function
- When the callback function is called reload all the contacts from address book.
- Use NSOperation and ensure isCancelled is handled.